# NodeJS Winston DailyRotateFile not writing

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm trying to setup a simple daily rotation log write with:

```
// Create file transport
transports.push(new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
  name: 'file',
  datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-ddTHH',
  filename: path.join(logPath, 'http')
}));

// Create new logger
var logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: transports
});
```

It's creating the log file just fine, however `logger.info(some_data)` doesn't write anything to the log.

Any thoughts, or even another solution?

Comment: Not seeing where in your code `log.info(some_data)` is used or where the variable `log` is instantiated.  I do see `logger`, but not `log`.

Comment: sorry, corrected, it was `logger.info`

Comment: Assuming it's not a Winston bug, `some_data` is not empty, and the logger is ready, either an error should have been generated or the file that was written to is somewhere you did not expect.  Perhaps insert a `logger.on('error', function (err) { /* Do Something */ });` and see if an error is being generated?

Comment: Or try a `console.log(some_data)` to see if `some_data` actually contains data. Or use a string for logger testing. Another solution could be to add the log level for the transport. If it is set to `error` for example, you wouldn't see `info` log requests.

Answer (score 2):

This one works with minute rotation:

```
var winston = require('winston');


var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({ filename: 'logFile', datePattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm' })
  ]
});


logger.info('Hello my friend');
```